# how to upload multiple images using single fileuploader button in 4.0

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0, file-upload

Hi coder i have a **fileupload button**  which is used to insert images from the system and save them into database now what i want is to select multiple images but using only single file uploader in **framework 4.0**

Each images has a priority as well

**Code:**

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    try
    {                                    
        Boolean enable = true;
        string relativepath = "https://Images/Module/" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "/";
        //Get imagename from fileupload control
        string imgName = fileuploadimages.FileName.ToString();
        //sets the image path if exist then store image in that place else create new one
        string imgPath = "images/Modules/" + "" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "/";
        bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
        if (!IsExists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
        //then save it to the Folder
        fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath + imgName));
        //Open the database connection
        con.Open();
        //Query to insert * into Images_Master into database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Image_Master(Userid,Image_Name,Description,ModuleId,pptId,Priority,Imageurl,RelativePath,IsEnable,dt) values('"+Session["trainer"]+"','" + imgName + "','" + tbDescription.Text + "','" + ddlModule.SelectedValue + "','" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "','" + lblPriority.Text + "',@Imageurl,'" + relativepath + "','" + enable + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')", con);
        //Passing parameters to query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image_Name", imgName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", tbDescription.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleId", ddlModule.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pptId", ddlPPT.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", lblPriority.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imageurl", imgPath + imgName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RelativePath", relativepath);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
        tbDescription.Text = "";
        Logs.InsertLogs(Session["Role"].ToString() + ":" + Session["trainer"].ToString(), "CreateModule.aspx.cs btn_Click", "Query Successfully Executed to insert image");
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Image uploaded..!!!');</script>");            
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

In this i select file using file upload button and click on btnSubmit to save image details in database now i want to select multiple images using upload button and on click on btnsubmit data save in database
Thanks in advance !!!!

Comment: multiple files are on same path or diffrent path ....

Comment: it may or may not be same but for now we can say select multiple images form single folder

Comment: Use Rad controls Multi-File upload, so simple. What you say? or is it necessary to use asp.net file upload.

Comment: i never use rad controls can you tell me in details about it or any article on it

Comment: you can itreate through all the files in folders...

Comment: can you give me some example @pankeel it would be a great help

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(Server.MapPath(imgPath));      

    List<string> filenames = new List<string>();
    for (int i = 0; i < files.Length; i++)
    {
 try
    {                                    
        Boolean enable = true;
        string relativepath = "https://Images/Module/" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "/";
        //Get imagename from fileupload control
        string imgName = fileuploadimages.FileName.ToString();
        //sets the image path if exist then store image in that place else create new one
        string imgPath = "images/Modules/" + "" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "/";
        bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
        if (!IsExists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
        //then save it to the Folder
        fileuploadimages.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath + Path.GetFileName(files[i])));
        //Open the database connection
        con.Open();
        //Query to insert * into Images_Master into database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Image_Master(Userid,Image_Name,Description,ModuleId,pptId,Priority,Imageurl,RelativePath,IsEnable,dt) values('"+Session["trainer"]+"','" + Path.GetFileName(files[i]) + "','" + tbDescription.Text + "','" + ddlModule.SelectedValue + "','" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "','" + lblPriority.Text + "',@Imageurl,'" + relativepath + "','" + enable + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')", con);
        //Passing parameters to query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image_Name", Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", tbDescription.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleId", ddlModule.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pptId", ddlPPT.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", lblPriority.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imageurl", imgPath + Path.GetFileName(files[i]));
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RelativePath", relativepath);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();           
        tbDescription.Text = "";
        Logs.InsertLogs(Session["Role"].ToString() + ":" + Session["trainer"].ToString(), "CreateModule.aspx.cs btn_Click", "Query Successfully Executed to insert image");
        Response.Write("<script>alert('Image uploaded..!!!');</script>");            
    }
    catch (Exception ex2)
    {

    }
    finally
    {
        if (con.State == ConnectionState.Open)
        {
            con.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: i fetch images from local computer folder

Comment: imgpath is used to store images not to select images my friends that images path is store in database so that i can use that path in other pages mate

Comment: it just like facebook where you select multiple images from a folder and then click on upload button and your images save in database

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to the default FileUploader control would be using [AjaxFileUploader](http://www.asp.net/ajaxlibrary/ajaxcontroltoolkitsamplesite/ajaxfileupload/ajaxfileupload.aspx) control. You will be able to select multiple files with only one button as in your case.

Just put this in markup:

```
    <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
            </asp:ScriptManager>
        <asp:AjaxFileUpload ID="AjaxFileUpload1" runat="server" 
        onuploadcomplete="AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete" AllowedFileTypes="jpg,jpeg"
        MaximumNumberOfFiles="10"/>
```

And add this method in code-behind:

```
protected void AjaxFileUpload1_UploadComplete(Object sender, AjaxFileUploadEventArgs e)
{
    // This method will be called after uploading each file
    if (e.FileName != String.Empty)
    {
        string relativepath = "https://Images/Module/" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "/";
        //Get imagename from fileupload control
        string imgName = e.FileName.ToString();
        //sets the image path if exist then store image in that place else create new one
        string imgPath = "images/Modules/" + "" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "/";
        bool IsExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
        if (!IsExists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Server.MapPath(imgPath));
        //then save it to the Folder
        AjaxFileUpload1.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(imgPath + imgName));
        //Open the database connection
        con.Open();
        //Query to insert * into Images_Master into database
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("Insert into Image_Master(Userid,Image_Name,Description,ModuleId,pptId,Priority,Imageurl,RelativePath,IsEnable,dt) values('" + Session["trainer"] + "','" + imgName + "','" + tbDescription.Text + "','" + ddlModule.SelectedValue + "','" + ddlPPT.SelectedValue + "','" + lblPriority.Text + "',@Imageurl,'" + relativepath + "','" + enable + "','" + DateTime.Now + "')", con);
        //Passing parameters to query
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Image_Name", imgName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Description", tbDescription.Text.Trim());
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ModuleId", ddlModule.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pptId", ddlPPT.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Priority", lblPriority.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Imageurl", imgPath + imgName);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@RelativePath", relativepath);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        tbDescription.Text = "";
        Logs.InsertLogs(Session["Role"].ToString() + ":" + Session["trainer"].ToString(), "CreateModule.aspx.cs btn_Click", "Query Successfully Executed to insert image");

        //you don't response.write here since the AjaxFileUploader already notify when image uploaded successfully
        //Response.Write("<script>alert('Image uploaded..!!!');</script>");  
    }
}
```

This way you can downlod multiple files to the server and save each file url in database.

Comment: jack the think is that my images didnt upload using ajax control i dont why when i select multiple images and click on upload button it doesn't show anything no progress bar to upload images nothing just stuck there

Comment: this means that you have a problem either in your markup or the browser, did you tried it on google chrome or firefox? also, make sure to add <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" /> in your web.config. If i can see the markup that would be better.

Comment: where to add tag in web.config file

Comment: in your web.config under <system.web> <pages> <controls> <add tagPrefix="asp" namespace="AjaxControlToolkit" assembly="AjaxControlToolkit" />

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49254/discussion-between-jack-kokah-and-amitesh)

Comment: since I cannot see your markup I suggest you see a tutorial about AjaxFileUploader and when it runs correctly then just apply it on your current page, it's a good control and you should know how to use it. See this tutorial http://www.dotnetfox.com/articles/ajax-fileupload-or-multiple-fileupload-with-progress-example-in-Asp-Net-1081.aspx